# How is this derived $p(Y^cR) = p(Y^c)-p(Y^cR^c)$

Tags: probability

How is this derived $$p(Y^cR) = p(Y^c)-p(Y^cR^c)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think in terms of a Venn diagram.

You can split $Y^c$ -- the event that $Y$ does not happen -- into two parts: $Y$ doesn't happen and $R$ does, and $Y$ doesn't happen and neither does $R$.

In other words:
$$
P(Y^c)=P((Y^c\cap R)\overset{\cdot}{\cup}(Y^c\cap R^c))=P(Y^c\cap R)+P(Y^c\cap R^c).
$$